# ¿Vincular dos controles checkbox en winforms?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo 2 checkbox que tiene de texto "Si" y el otro "No", son respuesta a una pregunta, lo que quiero hacer es si un checkbox esta seleccionado automaticamente deseleccionar el otro. Existe alguna propiedad que se pueda configurar para hacerlo sin yo asignar explicitamente el valor en el codigo?

Comment: mejor usa un radiobutton, automáticamente hará que se desactive el otro cuando seleccionas alguno

Comment: Gracias eso pensaba al principio, encontre que hay una propiedad que se llama RadioGroupIndex le estableci a los dos checks el numero 1 y listo ya cuando selecciono uno el otro se deselcciona y viceversa.